# Infinite List with bloc (List length not changing in the presentation layer) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, infinite-scroll, bloc

I am trying to load data from the api and i am using a bloc pattern for state management but when i call
load more when scrolling the the presentation layer only change when the hasReachedMax parameter is true
if it was false the ui still with the loading indicator

here is the presentation layer

```
              Flexible(
              child: Container(
                child: BlocConsumer<AllProjectsBloc, AllProjectsState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is AllProjectsLoadingState) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } **else if (state is AllProjectsLoadedState) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        controller: _scrollController,
                        itemCount: state.hasReachedMax ? state.allProjectsData.length  : 
                        state.allProjectsData.length +1 ,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                          return i >= 5 ? BottomLoader() : UnitCard(
                            price: state.allProjectsData[i].price,
                            date: state.allProjectsData[i].title.en,
                            image: state.allProjectsData[i].image,
                            bathroom: state.allProjectsData[i].bathroom,
                            bedroom: state.allProjectsData[i].bedroom,
                            area: state.allProjectsData[i].area,**

                            function:(){
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                             (context)=>DetailedProperty()));
                            });
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (state is FilteredProjectsLoadedState) {
                      return Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: state.filteredProjectsData.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                              return UnitCard(
                                price: 50,
                                date: '20/5/2020',
                                bedroom: 3,
                                bathroom: 2,
                                area: 120,
                                image: 
                  
                  
             'https://www.propertyturkey.com/uploads/realestate/larg/buyukcekmece_villa_1_8.jpg',
                                function:(){
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                     (context)=>DetailedProperty()));
                                } ,
                              );
                            },
                          ));
                    } else if (state is AllProjectsError) {
                      return ErrorView(
                          errorMessage: state.error.errorMessage,
                          retryAction: () {
                            BlocProvider.of<AllProjectsBloc>(context)
                                .add(state.failedEvent);
                          });
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                 
      }
```

the bloc class

```
     class AllProjectsBloc extends Bloc<AllProjectsEvents, AllProjectsState> {
        List<Data> propertyList = List();

           AllProjectsBloc() : super(AllProjectsInitialState());

         bool _hasReachedMax(AllProjectsState state) =>
            state is AllProjectsLoadedState && state.hasReachedMax;

         @override
        Stream<AllProjectsState> mapEventToState(AllProjectsEvents event) async* {
           bool isUserConnected = await NetworkUtilities.isConnected();
            if (isUserConnected == false) {
                yield AllProjectsError(
              failedEvent: event, error: Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                return;
             }
           if (event is FetchAllProjectsData && !_hasReachedMax(state)) {
               yield* _handleFetchingAllProject(event);
                      }

                  if (event is FetchFilteredProjectsData) {
          yield* _handleFetchingFilteredProject(event);
            return;
          }
            }

         Stream<AllProjectsState> _handleFetchingAllProject(
       FetchAllProjectsData event) async* {
       if (state is AllProjectsInitialState) {
  yield AllProjectsLoadingState();
  ResponseViewModel<List<Data>> handleProjectsFetchingResponse =
      await Repository.getAllPropertiesData(1);

  propertyList = handleProjectsFetchingResponse.responseData;
  print(propertyList.length);
  if (handleProjectsFetchingResponse.isSuccess) {
    yield AllProjectsLoadedState(
      allProjectsData: propertyList,
      hasReachedMax: false,
    );
  }
}
if (state is AllProjectsLoadedState) {
  ResponseViewModel<List<Data>> handleProjectsFetchingMoreResponse =
      await Repository.getAllPropertiesData(2);
  List<Data> tempList = handleProjectsFetchingMoreResponse.responseData;
  propertyList.addAll(tempList);

  if (handleProjectsFetchingMoreResponse.isSuccess) {
    yield AllProjectsLoadedState(
        allProjectsData: propertyList, hasReachedMax: true);
    print(propertyList.length);
  }
}
return;
   }
```

state class

```
                     class AllProjectsLoadedState extends AllProjectsState {

                final  List<Data>  allProjectsData;
                 final bool hasReachedMax ;

             AllProjectsLoadedState({this.allProjectsData , this.hasReachedMax}) : 
       super([allProjectsData , hasReachedMax]);

           AllProjectsLoadedState copyWith ({List<Data> allProjectsData , bool hasReachedMax }){
      return AllProjectsLoadedState(
        allProjectsData: allProjectsData ?? this.allProjectsData ,
        hasReachedMax:hasReachedMax ?? this.hasReachedMax
           );
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem i was yielding the same state and i am using equatable so the bloc consumer cannot recognize the changes in the state .. the solution is yield the loading state before yielding the LoadedState .